Does the Great Mazinger exist in the Grendizer-U storyline?
According to,
Why didn't Koji Kabuto have Mazinger Z anymore in the 80's Grendizer series

According to Wikipedia, there was a series inbetween those two, "Great
Mazinger". During that series, a new robot (the Great Mazinger) was
constructed, and arrived just in time to save the day as a new enemy
destroyed Mazinger Z. Koji survived, and left Japan after the battle
to study in America.

But in Grendizer U, Koji Kabuto was saved from Mazinger Z thanks to Grendizer, not to the Great Mazinger.
Then, does the Great Mazinger exist in the Grendizer U storyline?
